# IPFS 504 Gateway Time-out with public gateways from local node

Tags: ipfs, http-status-code-504

I installed Kubo on my local PC, I just entered the `ipfs daemon` command to run it. After that, I pushed some text content, it works fine and I can access it from the IPFS public gateway. But, when I put any image or file type of content and go to access it from a public IPFS gateway, it shows "504 Gateway Time-Out (Openresty)".  Also, it takes a long time to load any content, it's too slow. Is it possible to make it too fast? How can I fix the "504 Gateway Time-Out" issue?

Comment: This basically means the gateway server cannot get any response from the upstream server (an ipfs node) in time. Check that you're using the latest IPFS version, IPFS node is really running, or try switching to a different gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If the gateway cannot find the data you've requested, it will time out. A gateway is just an IPFS node with an HTTP server bolted onto it (more-or-less).

If the only node containing the data is your home node, you must [ensure your node is discoverable](https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/nat-configuration/) so the gateway node can find and access your data. Personally I like to put my data on [web3.storage](https://web3.storage) if I need the popular public gateways to find it.

For more info check out my answer on the related question [Why is it so hard for web browsers to open IPFS links?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063740/14051077).