# Why is it so hard for web browsers to open IPFS links?

Tags: ipfs

Why is it so hard for web browsers to open IPFS links?

For instance, this is an IPFS blog page link, https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeic3y6oc2dai3uypyyuaggp4xx3krocpgzbwst2z4ha73jdh7y6nea/index.html
, and the loading page is tremendously slow on Safari or Chrome/Edge, and it's stuck into Error 504 from time to time. Is there any way to browse IPFS pages smoothly? Or are IPFSs just internally incapable of smooth browsing without third-party helps?

Comment: Considering the amount if things happening in the background (cryptographically, logistically), the page loaded decently quick for me. It's in the nature of p2p to load blocks faster that are available on more nodes that are well known and widely distributed.

Comment: The reason why the objects are maybe loading slow from `https://ipfs.io` might be because that public page has a lot of traffic. You can setup your own client/proxy/api and try that instead: https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/

Comment: Wondering if there are other public gateways for ipfs that is not ipfs.io ?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the page through a gateway. So effectively, you're asking another (quite popular) IPFS node to fetch the info over IPFS, then serve it to you over HTTP. If the gateway is slowed down for any reason, all IPFS resources will seem slow to you. If a gateway is your only option for whatever reason, check out the [IPFS Gateway Checker](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) for a list of active ones.

Alternatively, you could run your own IPFS node via something like [IPFS Desktop](https://docs.ipfs.tech/install/ipfs-desktop/) then connect it to IPFS Companion ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipfs-companion/nibjojkomfdiaoajekhjakgkdhaomnch?hl=en) | [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/ipfs-companion/)). IPFS Companion can be configured to redirect all IPFS gateway links to your own IPFS node, then you'll be limited by just how quickly your node can find/retrieve the data, which you'll likely find to be the superior IPFS experience.

The Brave browser also includes an integrated IPFS node. They have an article about it [here](https://brave.com/ipfs-support/).

Comment: I might need to configure [port forwarding](https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/nat-configuration/) in order to share files over a gateway. I often get a "504 Gateway Timeout" error when I try to download them.