# How create a IPNS file. And download it form internet

Tags: ipfs

I create a file and publish it as ipfs file
`$ipfs add file added QmUVTKsrYJpaxUT7dr9FpKq6AoKHhEM7eG1ZHGL56haKLG`

next I publish it to ipns

`$ipfs name publish QmUVTKsrYJpaxUT7dr9FpKq6AoKHhEM7eG1ZHGL56haKLG Published to k51qzi5uqu5dltd25mh4mbpenvt48ogf896tmzwps60sdsifmh6jbsi5nc432x`

and check , resolve correct

`$ipfs name resolve k51qzi5uqu5dltd25mh4mbpenvt48ogf896tmzwps60sdsifmh6jbsi5nc432x /ipfs/QmUVTKsrYJpaxUT7dr9FpKq6AoKHhEM7eG1ZHGL56haKLG` 
trouble is with download it.
`curl https://ipfs.io/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dltd25mh4mbpenvt48ogf896tmzwps60sdsifmh6jbsi5nc432x`
is alvays **504 Gateway Time-out**

I expect download my data. I wayting about a week.

Comment: Is this about networking?

Comment: @JamesRisner https://ipfs.tech/ yes, it is network

Comment: @JamesRisner Your comments are aggressive and are completely out of topic.

Comment: @Łukasz I mistook you for the op. As for aggressive, it wasn’t intended. Stackoverflow is only for programming or related questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
I don’t see any code or how this is related to programming.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006860/ipfs-504-gateway-time-out-issue-with-localhost/75377060 and @JamesRisner is correct, it's not on-topic.